# Liferay portal 6.2 - Asset publisher template for showing Knowledge Base Articles

Tags: templates, liferay, velocity

Hi I am trying to create a custom template for Asset Publisher portlet, to show my Knowledge Base Articles. For doing this, I need to retrieve

1. Entry title
2. Entry content
3. Create Date

I can find the title and the date but there's no method to get the content. Any help?

```
##
## This template can be used to modify the look of a specific
## application.
##
## Please use the left panel to quickly add commonly used variables.
## Autocomplete is also available and can be invoked by typing "$".
##

#if (!$entries.isEmpty())
    #foreach ($curEntry in $entries)
        <div>
        <p>News 1:<br/>
        $curEntry.getTitle($locale) <br />
        $curEntry.getCreateDate() <br />
        $curEntry.getDescription()<br /></p>
        </div>
    #end
#end
```

As you can see in the code above, I tried "getDescription()" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`$curEntry` is an `AssetEntry` instance, it's not the a Knowledge Base Article.

You can use `$curEntry.getClassPK()` to retrieve the Knowledge Base Article instance using Knowledge Base Article service.

Answer (score 1):

If you check AssetEntry table in database you will find description column is empty, so you will not get any data you want.

You can get asset data by using below code:

```
#foreach ($curEntry in $entries)
    Title: $curEntry.getTitle($locale)<br/>
    Published date: $entry.getPublishDate()<br/>
    Summary: **$entry.getAssetRenderer().getSummary($locale)** <br/>
#end
```

Now how above code is working. Summary we want, do lie in JournelArticle class(table). Interface AssetRender is implemented by class JournalArticleAssetRenderer. This class inherits getSummary(Locale locale) method. This method contains object of JournetArticle class.

```
JournelContent obj; 
public String getSummary(Locale locale) {
    return obj.getDescription(locale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
#if (!$entries.isEmpty())
<div class="news">
#foreach ($entry in $entries)
#set($renderer = $entry.getAssetRenderer() )
#set($className = $renderer.getClassName() )
#if( $className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" )
#set( $journalArticle = $renderer.getArticle() )
#set( $document = $saxReaderUtil.read($journalArticle.getContent()) )
#set( $rootElement = $document.getRootElement() )
#set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='image']") )
#set( $image = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue() )
#set( $link = $renderer.getURLViewInContext($renderRequest, $renderResponse, '') )
<div class="new"">
<h1 class="title">$entry.getTitle($locale)</h1>
<div"><img src="$image" ></div>
<a href="$link">Read More</a>           
</div>
#end
#end
</div>
#end
```